# Moving Game Object with UI Buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up control of Player game object by UI buttons.
2d top down view scene.

I want to transfer Player object smoothly on fixed distance (0.8 for Axix X for left-right direction and 2.4 for up-down)when I release left/right/up/down ui buttons.

Here i found code for smooth movement but there Player is moving all the time while ui button is pressed.

Can you help me to make it move on mouse up (pointer up) and to move for `public x= 0.8f` for left/right, and `public y = 2.4f` for up/down

And at the same time i want to use different speed (peblic) for moves on x and y Axis

Its ok if it should be totally other script using `smth` like `transform.translate`
Kindly guide to for any possible solution for this. Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    float movX;
    float movY;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movY = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

          rb.velocity = new Vector2(movX * 1, movY * 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like you can get the answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471129/use-eventsystem-for-key-pressing-events

Comment: You are probably not applying enough force.  Change those `* 1` to `* 100` and adjust to taste.  Also you don't need to make `movX`/`movY` instance variables if you don't use them elsewhere.

Comment: The matter is that object is moving but i need it to move on constant value when  Button (Image sprite with collider) is Up. Actualy i dont need here phisycs that is why trying to go through transform.translate. But cant handle because unskillfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script can be moved by the WASD keys.
This should move your gameObject by the requested amount over x amount of time(speed).
Currently it can be only moved when it'S reached its destionation but you can easily modify this :), by stopping the coroutine

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // We gonna move by WASD keys

    [Header("Speed & Movement settings")]
    [SerializeField]
    float Speed = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    float movSpeedX = 0.8f;
    [SerializeField]
    float movSpeedY = 2.4f;

    bool ReachedTarget = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if (ReachedTarget)
        {
            Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;
            Vector2 currentPos = transform.position;
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
            {
                dest = currentPos + (Vector2.up * movSpeedY);
                StartCoroutine(moveTo(dest, Speed));
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
            {
                dest = currentPos + (Vector2.down * movSpeedY);
                StartCoroutine(moveTo(dest, Speed));
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
            {
                dest = currentPos + (Vector2.right * movSpeedX);
                StartCoroutine(moveTo(dest, Speed));
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
            {
                dest = currentPos + (Vector2.left * movSpeedX);
                StartCoroutine(moveTo(dest, Speed));
            }
        }
    }

    // Time to take is in seconds
    IEnumerator moveTo(Vector2 TargetPosition, float TimetoTake)
    {
        Vector2 originalPosition = transform.position;
        float Time_taken = 0f;
        ReachedTarget = false;
        while (Time_taken < 1)
        {
            Time_taken += Time.deltaTime / TimetoTake;
            // Interpolating between the original and target position this basically provides your "speed"
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(originalPosition, TargetPosition, Time_taken);
            yield return null;
        }
        Time_taken = 0;
        transform.position = TargetPosition;
        ReachedTarget = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201903/discussion-on-answer-by-menyus-moving-game-object-with-ui-buttons).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation of `CrossPlatformInputManager`, and I know nothing about it. But if you need to get the event of "release a key" instead of "press the key", try this: [Input.GetKeyUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html).

> ***Description***
>
> Returns true during the frame the user releases the key identified by
>   name.
>
> You need to call this function from the Update function, since the
>   state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user
>   has pressed the key and released it again.
>
> For the list of key identifiers see Conventional Game Input. When
>   dealing with input it is recommended to use Input.GetAxis and
>   Input.GetButton instead since it allows end-users to configure the
>   keys.
>
> ```
> using UnityEngine;
> using System.Collections;
>
> public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     void Update()
>     {
>         if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
>         {
>             print("Space key was released");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

If you want to stop the rigid body, you need to reset its velocity to
zero. Or you can use
[Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)
to move it a certain distance.

> ***Parameters***
>
> *position*    *The new position for the Rigidbody object.*
>
> ***Description***
>
> Moves the rigidbody to position.
>
> Moves the rigidbody to the specified position by calculating the
>   appropriate linear velocity required to move the rigidbody to that
>   position during the next physics update. During the move, neither
>   gravity or linear drag will affect the body. This causes the object to
>   rapidly move from the existing position, through the world, to the
>   specified position.
>
> Because this feature allows a rigidbody to be moved rapidly to the
>   specified position through the world, any colliders attached to the
>   rigidbody will react as expected i.e. they will produce collisions
>   and/or triggers. This also means that if the colliders produce a
>   collision then it will affect the rigidbody movement and potentially
>   stop it from reaching the specified position during the next physics
>   update. If the rigidbody is kinematic then any collisions won't affect
>   the rigidbody itself and will only affect any other dynamic colliders.
>
> 2D rigidbodies have a fixed limit on how fast they can move therefore
>   attempting to move large distances over short time-scales can result
>   in the rigidbody not reaching the specified position during the next
>   physics update. It is recommended that you use this for relatively
>   small distance movements only.
>
> It is important to understand that the actual position change will
>   only occur during the next physics update therefore calling this
>   method repeatedly without waiting for the next physics update will
>   result in the last call being used. For this reason, it is recommended
>   that it is called during the FixedUpdate callback.
>
> Note: MovePosition is intended for use with kinematic rigidbodies.
>
> ```
> // Move sprite bottom left to upper right.  It does not stop moving.
> // The Rigidbody2D gives the position for the cube.
>
> using UnityEngine;
> using System.Collections;
>
> public class Example : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     public Texture2D tex;
>
>     private Vector2 velocity;
>     private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
>     private Sprite mySprite;
>     private SpriteRenderer sr;
>
>     void Awake()
>     {
>         sr = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
>         rb2D = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
>     }
>
>     void Start()
>     {
>         mySprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
>         velocity = new Vector2(1.75f, 1.1f);
>         sr.color = new Color(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
>
>         transform.position = new Vector3(-2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
>         sr.sprite = mySprite;
>     }
>
>     void FixedUpdate()
>     {
>         rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
>     }
> }
> ```

Both documents have an example.
Or you don't want to user keyboard but UI buttons, try this: [IPointerDownHandler and IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html)

> Description
>   Interface to implement if you wish to receive OnPointerDown callbacks.
>
> Detects ongoing mouse clicks until release of the mouse button. Use
>   IPointerUpHandler to handle the release of the mouse button.
>
> ```
> //Attach this script to the GameObject you would like to have mouse clicks detected on
> //This script outputs a message to the Console when a click is currently detected or when it is released on the GameObject with this script attached
>
> using UnityEngine;
> using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
>
> public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
> {
>     //Detect current clicks on the GameObject (the one with the script attached)
>     public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
>     {
>         //Output the name of the GameObject that is being clicked
>         Debug.Log(name + "Game Object Click in Progress");
>     }
>
>     //Detect if clicks are no longer registering
>     public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
>     {
>         Debug.Log(name + "No longer being clicked");
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is a very good answer but it is almost base on Live Links. As soon as they disappear, the answer will be useless. Please edit your comment and add some of the information that can be found on the link.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego all of the links are pointing to the offical Unity documentation, so it's okey

Comment: Note that for the IPointerXYHandler you also need to: `Ensure an Event System exists in the Scene` (usually added automatically when adding a `UI.Canvas`)